# Steps to add indexer tiers in druid

Tags: druid, indexer, data-ingestion

How to setup indexer tier in Apache Druid version 28.0.0?
Need to change this _Default_tier to new_tier
[druid-console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG3tk.png)

I tried adding below parameter and then restarted druid, but no change was found.

druid.worker.category=test
druid.worker.capacity=5